# How a function can detect if I'm giving a HEX or a RGB and therefore convert it from one to another?

Tags: javascript

I need a function that converts RGB to HEX and HEX to RGB. I've seen other solutions with different functions for each of the problems but I need one that can distinguish if I'm giving it RBG/HEX. For example, I want it to know if I'm giving three parameters (255, 255, 255) or only one (#000000)

```
function convertRGBHEX (given value: can be HEX or RGB){
do stuff
return
}
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about your input. On one hand you say "rgb", but it's not clear if you are talking about the CSS notation, which can be represented in many ways. Then, you are saying that you'll give the parameters as `(255, 255, 255)` this seems to imply that you are not talking about CSS notation, but just about  some format you made taking each channels as separated numeric value (I guess in the range [0-255]. If that is so, then it's quite easy, but you need to clarify it. Same for your hex value, currently it's not noted as a string and is simply invalid in js,

Comment: but we need to know which format you want to handle (3 4 6 8 length? numeric value? etc.). TLDR: Where does your input comes from? And additionally why do you need this?

Comment: Yes, I want each channel separated in the RGB case. About the hex, you're right. It should be a string and in that format, a hash + 6 numbers. The input will come from me in the console. Sorry if I'm not clear enough, I'm just starting with this and I was just practicing an exercise from a course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following using regex matching (this is not strict matching for ex `(266,1,1)` is not a valid RGB but would be considered as a valid one ...you can upgrade the regex for more precise results):

```js
function convertRGBHEX(param) {
  if (param.match(/^#[0-9a-f]{3,6}$/i)) {
    //do stuff if param given is hash
    console.log('gving param is a hash')
  } else if (param.match(/\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)$/)) {
    // do stuff if param given is rgb
    console.log('gving param is rgb')
  } else {
   console.log('not both')
  }
}
convertRGBHEX('#fff')
convertRGBHEX('(11,54,255)')
convertRGBHEX('red')
```